# <list> in conntrollers and views

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am new to programming in java. I have successfully created and described the connection between the models release, event, podcast and other.
 
I need to show 4 links to the 4 latest release, 4 events and so on ...

At the moment my application controller contains:

```
public static void index() {
    Label lastLabel = Label.find("order by name desc").first();
    Release lastRelease = Release.find("order by title").first();
    Event lastEvent = Event.find("order by title").first();
    Podcast lastPodcast = Podcast.find("order by title").first();
    render(lastLabel, lastRelease, lastEvent, lastPodcast);
}
```

in index.html I use:

```
${lastPodcast.artist.name}
```

and other tags.
I cannot figure out how to put the 4 values ​​in the array and display them on the screen.

Comment: How come you're using such an old version of Play?

Comment: Why are you starting with old-stable release of framework ? Current stable is 2.1 - and whole 2.x brunch quite different from 1.x brunch. It also supports Java programming of course

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Podcast> podcasts = Podcast.find("order by name desc").fetch(4);
render(labels);
```

in index.html:

```
#{list items: labels, as:'item'}
     <p>${item.artist.name}</p>
#{/list}
```

Check out the tags from here:
 http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.1/tags

Comment: thx. but why you used `(render labels);` and `list items: labels if List<Podcast> podcasts` ?